# How to reset monitor display settings?

Tags: display, catalyst

On Ubuntu 12.04 laptop with Gnome desktop, I tried to set an additional display through Catalyst (administrative) and slowly ended up making making a mess out of the whole thing. I tried several combinations of settings and at each iterration I just made things worse, ending up with 'mail battery sound time user power' icons repeating on the top bar. Now I'm lost as to how to restore everything to default settings.

Answer (score 8):

Delete the file `~/.config/monitors.xml`.

Comment: is there a reboot/relogin or some other reload needed?

Answer (score 4):

try 
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf 
and reboot your system 
which will delete your X server setting so next time you reboot x server will try to detect your optimal setting , and i solved a problem which faced me with resolution with the same method

Comment: works on ubuntu 13.04 too